# RestKit request seems to work only once

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, restkit

Alright I've been debugging the whole day but can't figure out what the problem is with my code.

The goal is to send a POST with RestKit to the Heroku API with a username/password to retrieve the API key.

The problem is that I'm only able to sent the request once. When sending the request the second time I get errors. (So first time I do get the API key binded to my object, but the second time just a error)

I'm using the current version of RestKit (0.10)

**The code:**

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObject:(id)object
{
    Account *account = (Account *)object;
    NSLog(@"API_KEY: %@", account.apiKey);
}

- (IBAction) login:(id)sender
{
    Account *account = [[Account alloc] init];
    account.email = [emailField text];
    account.password = [passwordField text];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:account delegate:self];
}
```

**LOG**

```
/// ---> FIRST CLICK
2012-05-25 14:57:00.028 HerokuApp[11154:fb03] API_KEY: 1234567890
/// ---> SECOND CLICK
2012-05-25 14:57:03.427 HerokuApp[11154:fb03] W restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:281 Unable to find parser for MIME Type 'text/html'
2012-05-25 14:57:03.427 HerokuApp[11154:fb03] W restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:309 Encountered unexpected response with status code: 200 (MIME Type: text/html -> URL: https://api.heroku.com/login -- https://api.heroku.com -- https://api.heroku.com -- https://api.heroku.com)
2012-05-25 14:57:03.429 HerokuApp[11154:fb03] didFailWithError: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain error 4.)"
```

Can anybody help me explaining why this behaviour is occuring?

Comment: Printing out error description might be helpful. `NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);`

Comment: @Kreiri updated my post with the new log output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the API behaves differently when you are logged in.  From your log messages, it is appearing to return back text/html content, and not something that RestKit knows how to deal with.

Run in the simulator on a machine where Wireshark is capturing packets.  Reproduce the error, then find the TCP stream where this is happening and look at it.  If you need help, update your question with the result of "Follow Stream" in Wireshark so that we can see the full HTTP traffic.